# Symfony - how to know if console command was run from controller or it was run from terminal?

Tags: php, authentication, console-application, symfony

I am building Symfony Application that use console commands. The same console command can be executed from controller thrue events, but it also can be run from terminal. How can I figure it out from where the command was run so that I can implement the user authentication if the command was run from terminal. If the command was run from controller then user already has permission to run. But if it has been run from terminal he must authenticate by username and password so that I check if he has necessary role?

Comment: Shouldn't you just check if user is logged in?

Comment: console commands are not meant to be run from the web. By the way, if someone has access to the terminal, any permission-check is probably useless as he has access to all the files

Comment: I run command by pheanstalk to update data into infuxDB. But I want to add option to run command by terminal if the update is not executed correctly or if something go wrong. But he must authenticate and I must check for role. There is additional security on server to restrict access by ip so there is no problem with that. But there is many emploies with access from internal ip so I wouldn't like that the command is run by someone who don't know for sure what he is doing.

Comment: @u_mulder How can I check if he is logged in if he is in terminal. The sf aplication that send data into pheanstalk in on the different server and is also different sf app only for web. I have another app for parsing data and inserting into DB and some other functions for manipulating data. This is also the reason that are 2 different apps. So the users have only access to web app and they don't have access to app that manipulate data.

Comment: I was thinking that I will add argument secret key or something and in web app I will use that key to avoid authentication, and of course delete help text for this argument from console help, But this is bad solution, so i am looking for better one :)

Comment: Look at my answer. Basically inverting the logic and stripping any console command stuff out web context is the key. Why let users fiddle with a shell command, when it could be simple as a click of a button in a web app?

Answer (score 22):

You can check if your command was run from the console or from a controller using [php_sapi_name() function](http://php.net/manual/function.php-sapi-name.php) or [PHP_SAPI constant](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-sapi) (which is similar to php_sapi_name())

```
if ('cli' === PHP_SAPI) {
    // command was run from the console
} else {
    // command was run from a controller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The symfony Console Application has no firewall layer like the HttpKernel.

The console component was built for small 'admin like' tasks, not sth that is facing an individual user.

The whole problem could be solved by implementing a commandbus pattern.

The "command" is created by the web controller that is secured and has a user and in the CLI command (for crontab) without any security checks.

Then its passed to the command bus that handles over to the Command Handler.

The Handler contains the current logic of the execute method. The Command Object would contain any data to execute these logic == your current input arguments and options.

The Symfony Command afterwards is very slim, like just passing input args to command handler. Like it should be.

If it is a long running task it could even be offloaded from the web request to an worker queue.

Please mind the naming collision. A symfony console command !== command bus command here.

For example, you could use SimpleBus inside Symfony: 
https://github.com/SimpleBus

Also the recent blog post on the naming issue by @skoop: 
http://leftontheweb.com/blog/2016/06/18/Command-or-Controller/