# Symfony service configuration based on request

Tags: php, symfony

I have a configuration value where I define an event listener for one of the Doctrine events and I am using DI for the services needed in the listener.

```
$services->set(ExamplePrePersistListener::class)
    ->tag('doctrine.event_listener', ['event' => 'prePersist', 'priority' => 500]);
```

This listener is triggered during an http request, so one of the dependecies I have is a service (UserBuilder) that gets a logged in user from the session. But now I need to trigger this same listener during a cli request, so my idea is to refactor the listener to expect the dependency via an interface (UserBuilderInterface), so that I am able to define which implementation to send during the different request. I would end up with two implementations HttpUserBuilder, CliUserBuilder.

My question is how do I tell Symfony to send each of the implementations based on the request? How do I setup the listener in the config file in a way to be able to decide for the given implementation?

Comment: By `request` you are not talking about the actual $request object are you?  You are actually trying to do something different based on a console app (cli) or a web app (http)?

Comment: @Cerad Correct, by request I mean the http or the cli request (or entry point), not a request object.

Comment: You can make a [service locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) containing your two UserBuilderInterface services and then use something like `if ('cli' === PHP_SAPI) {` to pick the correct one.  Bit of a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021579/symfony-how-to-know-if-console-command-was-run-from-controller-or-it-was-run-f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Cerad in the comments I decided to do a simple if check `if ('cli' === PHP_SAPI)` to figure out if I am running from the cli or not. Although this solves my issues with dependencies such as the ones I have in my Value Objects, this did not quite solve my issue asked in the question for the Doctrine listener, but I modified my initial idea to suite for this.

The issue with the Doctrine listener is that I don't know which dependency to send at runtime, so one option is to have the if check in the services.php config file (and send it via args method), but it felt hacky to do it, mostly because I want to migrate to yaml configuration. Another option would be to set it a setter dependency based on a configuration value (is_cli or something similar), but then I would need to always set this parameter when running from the CLI.

So I went with the current UserBuilder and using the service locator that @Cerad mentioned. I am anyway using the Builder pattern, so the builder class can decide if I am in CLI or not, instead of having two separate builder classes (CliUserBuilder and HttpUserBuilder) and then a third place that decides which one to send. The second one might be a better separation of concerns, but I can't be bothered of adding an additional layer of configuration only for the sake of it.

My UserBuilder class looks like this:

```
final class UserBuilder implements ServiceSubscriberInterface
{
    use ServiceSubscriberTrait;

    public function build(): User
    {
        if ('cli' === PHP_SAPI) {
            return $this->buildFromCliRequest();
        }

        return $this->buildFromHttpRequest();
    }

    public function buildFromCliRequest(): User
    {
        return $this->createUserRepository()->find(
            $this->createConfig()->getAutomatedUserId()
        );
    }

    public function buildFromHttpRequest(): ?User
    {
        // Get user context from the http request
        // $authContext = $this->createRequestStack()->getCurrentRequest() ...

        return $this->createUserRepository()->find(
            $authContext->getUser()->getId()
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return RequestStack
     */
    #[SubscribedService]
    public function createRequestStack(): RequestStack
    {
        return $this->container->get(__METHOD__);
    }

    /**
     * @return UserRepository
     */
    #[SubscribedService]
    public function createUserRepository(): UserRepository
    {
        return $this->container->get(__METHOD__);
    }

    /**
     * @return Config
     */
    #[SubscribedService]
    public function createConfig(): Config
    {
        return $this->container->get(__METHOD__);
    }
}
```

The service locator creates only proxies to these dependencies as far as I understand, so they are not instantiated until being called, meaning if I am in CLI then the RequestStack will never get called.

This also allowed me for minimal refactoring, so I guess I can live with it.